# Problema com dataTable selection, e como acessar um var fora do método repeat (primeFaces)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Olá

Tenho uma tela em que listo alguns registros por meio do datatable (primefaces)

1) No meu Bean tenho duas listas uma que alimento com os registros retornados do banco e a outra que 
será usada pelo selection do datatable para armazenar os itens selecionados na tela

```
@Getter @Setter
private List<RegistrosDTO> listaRegistros;

@Getter @Setter
private List<RegistrosDTO> listaRegistrosSelecionados;
```

Em uma segunda Tela irei exibir os ids dos itens selecionados na tela anterior, para isso estou usando a 
função repeat

```
<ui:repeat value="#{meuBBean.listaRegistrosSelecionados}"                                                                   
           var="registrosSelecionados" 
       varStatus="status">

    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:outputText
            value="#{registro.id}" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:repeat>
```

O Problema aqui é que está exibindo somente o primeiro item da lista, por exemplo:

Registros Selecionados na primeira tela:  100, 101

Registros exibido na segunda tela:        100

2) Além de exibir os ids dos registros que estão dentro do laço repeat, preciso os demais atributos mas 
esses fora do bloco repeat pois são iguais para todos registros ex.:

var="registrosSelecionados" 
               varStatus="status">

```
        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:outputText value="#{registrosSelecionados.id}" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGrid>

 <h:panelGroup>
    <h:outputText value="#{registrosSelecionados.nome}" />
 </h:panelGroup>
```

O problema aqui é que não consigo acessar o var=registrosSelecionados fora do bloco repeat, tentei usar o 
componente dataGrid para ter um var visível dentro do repeat e fora dele, mas também não deu certo.

Alguma idéia para me ajudar nisso aqui ?

Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Olá

Consegui resolver está questão,

1) No primeiro item o "problema" e que meu meuBBean.listaRegistrosSelecionados estava trazendo dois registros iguais(100, 100) e na hora de exibir dentro do bloco repeat ele faz uma especie de "DISTINCT" e dessa forma exibe somente um registro (100). Quando a lista traz dois registros diferentes (100,101) eles são exibidos corretamente dentro do bloco repeat.

2) O var=registrosSelecionados realmente somente será visto dentro do bloco repeat, e para pegar o dado fora do bloco eu estava falhando em não mencionar o indice conforme abaixo:

value="#{meuBBean.listaRegistrosSelecionados.get(0).nome}"